# PHP not shown multiple rows

Tags: php, row, multiple-columns

I use these to show my table with rows:

It just show a row, but i have about 300rows in mysql.

I don't know what's problem? Anyone can help me?

I tried to use this code:

```
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$hour = $dnn['BanH']; $day = $dnn['BanD']; $month = $dnn['BanM']; $year = $dnn['BanY'];
$uhour = $dnn['UnbanH']; $uday = $dnn['UnbanD']; $umonth = $dnn['UnbanM']; $uyear = $dnn['UnbanY'];
$yaro = $dnn['Name']; $dalil = $dnn['Reason']; $bokon = $dnn['Admin'];

if($dnn['Days'] == 0) {
        $bantime = "Never <font color=red>(Banned Permanently)</font>";
}
else {
        $bantime = "$uday/$umonth/$uyear, $uhour:00";
}

$banlist = "<tr><td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\"><a href=User-{$yaro}><font color=white>{$yaro}</a></font></td>
<td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\">{$day}/{$month}/{$year}, {$hour}:00</td>
<td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\">{$bantime}</td>
<td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\">{$dalil}</td>
<td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\">{$bokon}</td>
</tr>";
}
if($banlist == '')
{
        $banlist = '<tr><td colspan="5">'.$lang->no_banned.'</td></tr>';
}
$bans .= $banlist;

$page = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Banned Users List</title>
{$headerinclude}
</head>
<body>
{$header}
<br />
<table border=0 cellspacing={$theme['borderwidth']} cellpadding={$theme['tablespace']} class=tborder>
<tr>
<td class=thead colspan=5><span class=smalltext><strong>Banned Users List</strong></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=tcat align=center>Player</td>
<td class=tcat align=center>Ban Date</td>
<td class=tcat align=center>Unban Date</td>
<td class=tcat align=center>Ban Reason</td>
<td class=tcat align=center>Banned By</td>
</tr>
{$bans}
</tbody></table>

{$footer}
</body>
</html>";
output_page($page);
```

i tried to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php examples.
** Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: use mysqli instead of mysql in your codes.

Comment: do you get any errors??

Comment: share your SQL query.

Comment: @zahraj I used mysqli too but i didn't get any error.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim $query = mysql_query('SELECT * from bans order by uid desc');

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong way. Within the loop every time, the value of `banlist` is being overridden - so, you are getting only the value of the last row.

You will need to do like this:

```
$banlist = '';
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$hour = $dnn['BanH']; $day = $dnn['BanD']; $month = $dnn['BanM']; $year = $dnn['BanY'];
$uhour = $dnn['UnbanH']; $uday = $dnn['UnbanD']; $umonth = $dnn['UnbanM']; $uyear = $dnn['UnbanY'];
$yaro = $dnn['Name']; $dalil = $dnn['Reason']; $bokon = $dnn['Admin'];

if($dnn['Days'] == 0) {
        $bantime = "Never <font color=red>(Banned Permanently)</font>";
}
else {
        $bantime = "$uday/$umonth/$uyear, $uhour:00";
}

$banlist .= "<tr><td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\"><a href=User-{$yaro}><font color=white>{$yaro}</a></font></td>
<td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\">{$day}/{$month}/{$year}, {$hour}:00</td>
<td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\">{$bantime}</td>
<td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\">{$dalil}</td>
<td class=\"trow1\" align=\"center\">{$bokon}</td>
</tr>";
}
```

Comment: after the loop finishes, what does `var_dump($banlist)` returns?

Comment: string(303) "Tested 7/7/2016, 14:00 17/7/2016, 14:00 Test Testor "